# laravel model relationships hasOne

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two table, the first is accounts (User model) which is used for auth and the other is students (t_student model) which contains the students details such student id (S_ID)

I am trying to get the S_ID inside the controller in store function for the logged in user.

```
     $application = new Application;
     $application->A_ID= $request-> input('A_ID');
     $application->S_ID= Auth()->User()->students()->S_ID;
     $application->S_Justification= $request-> input('Justification');
     $application->save();
     return redirect('/Abstracts')->with ('success', 'application submitted' );
```

MY User model (accounts table)

```
class User extends Authenticatable{

protected $table = 'accounts';
protected $primaryKey = 'Account_ID';

use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
     'email', 'password', 'Account_Type', 'name'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
public function abstracts(){
    return $this ->hasMany('App\Project' , 'PI_ID');
}
public function academics(){
    return $this ->hasOne('App\T_user', 'Account_ID');
}
public function students(){
    return $this ->hasOne('App\t_student', 'Account_ID');
}}
```

my t_student model

```
class t_student extends Model{
protected $table = 't_student';
protected $primaryKey = 'S_ID';

public function account(){
return $this ->belongsTo('App\User', 'Account_ID');}
```

and I am getting this error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$S_ID
```

EDIT: The error I am getting is related to my controller

```
         $application->S_ID= Auth()->User()->students()->S_ID;
```

and the reason is my relationship but I am not sure what is wrong about it

Comment: The reason is `Auth()->User()->students()` return one `HasOne` relation, you have to use `first()` to retrieve data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify it:

```
$application->S_ID= Auth()->User()->students->S_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

In User model u must added the foregnkey to second parameter in hasOne func 
so replace the Account_ID by S_ID 
for ex :

```
// in user model   
public function students()
{
   return $this ->hasOne('App\t_student', 'S_ID');
}
 // in ur controller romove the parentheses of students propriety
```